# How to get data rows with COUNT() in JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `inventory` and `tickets`, i want to obtain machine details stored in inventory with  more that 3 reported tickets. the common row between these two tables is `machine_name`.

```
inventory                                 tickets

machine_name|location|macaddress          tkt_no|machine_name|problem
---------------------------------------   ----------------------------
fad.dfsd.dg|lab1     |aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff   01    |fgr.sds.ss  |Network
fgr.sds.ss |lab3     |bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa   02    |fgr.sds.ss  |HDD  
ggr.sds.se |lab1     |11:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa   03    |fad.dfsd.dg |HDD 
                                          04    |fad.dfsd.dg |Monitor
                                          05    |fad.dfsd.dg |Other
                                          06    |fad.dfsd.dg |Power
                                          07    |ggr.sds.se  |Monitor
                                          08    |fgr.sds.ss  |Power
                                          09    |fgr.sds.ss  |Other
                                          10    |fgr.sds.ss  |Monitor
                                          11    |fgr.sds.ss  |Mouse
                                          12    |ggr.sds.se  |Power
```

This is what i have tried:

```
SELECT i.machine_name, i.location, i.macaddress, COUNT(t.machine_name) AS cnt
FROM inventory AS i
RIGHT JOIN tickets AS t USING(machine_name)
GROUP BY t.machine_name
HAVING cnt > 3
```

I want this query to return something like

```
machine_name | location |macaddress        | cnt
------------------------------------------------
fad.dfsd.dg  | lab1     |aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff | 4
fgr.sds.ss   | lab3     |bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa | 6
```

but i get all null values except for count

```
machine_name | location |macaddress  | cnt
------------------------------------------
null         | null     |null        | 4
null         | null     |null        | 6
```

Can someone assist on how i can obtain the results i want?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.machine_name, i.location, i.macaddress, COUNT(t.machine_name) AS cnt
FROM inventory AS i
JOIN tickets AS t USING(machine_name)
GROUP BY i.machine_name, i.location, i.macaddress
HAVING cnt > 3
```

Comment: Sorry but the query above return empty rows. Does it require the table foreign keys be set?

Comment: You should add example data of both tables to your question.

Comment: May be it is something to do with mysql, because even the fiddle codes does not work on mysql am using `Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)` ?

Comment: The MySQL version should be fine. I have no idea why it is not working in your environment.